# How to append data properly to a JSON using python

Tags: python, json

Update:
The only issue I have now is when running the command to add a user it create a completely duplicate key.

**Question:
json.dump() simply adds the entry to the end of the json, I want it to overwrite the entire file with the new updated entry**

Setup: (Create blank "Banks" Field)

```
        with open(DATA_FILENAME, mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            data = {"banks": []}
            json.dump(data, f)
```

Set User: (Create a User Key inside "Banks")

```
            member = ctx.message.author
            entry = {'name': member.name, 'id': member.id, 'balance': 0}

            with open(DATA_FILENAME, 'r+') as outfile:
                data = json.load(outfile)
                data['banks'].append((entry))
                json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
```

Output of first use:

```
{"banks": []}{
    "banks": [
        {
            "name": "ViperZ-14",
            "id": 367151547575959562,
            "balance": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

What I need:

```
{
    "banks": [
        {
            "name": "ViperZ-14",
            "id": 367151547575959562,
            "balance": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Use `append` i.e. `'a'` when opening a file @Jamie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you append to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: that directly appends the text, i would like it to be formated i.e. with seperators like commas and placed inside of [] and such @Vishnudev

Comment: Read the file, load the json onto a variable, append data to that variable and write to the file.

Comment: @Vishnudev above is my attempt to what you stated, for some reason it throws an error at line 29 which is the json.load().

Comment: @Jamie which error?

Comment: The error was caused by it being write only and trying to read. The last and only issue i have now is, its adding to the end of the json even though i just want it to imput the new key/tables

Comment: @Vishnudev what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file_path = '/home/vishnudev/Downloads/new.json'
import json

def load(file, mode, data=[]):
    with open(file, mode) as f:
        if mode == 'r':
            return json.load(f)
        elif mode == 'w':
            json.dump(data, f)

def get_data_func():
    return {
        'name': 'vishnu',
        'data': 'dev'
    }

d = load(file_path, 'r')
print(d)

d.append(get_data_func())

load(file_path, 'w', d)

d = load(file_path, 'r')
print(d)
```

**Output:**

On running the above twice I get

```
[{'name': 'vishnu', 'data': 'dev'}]
[{'name': 'vishnu', 'data': 'dev'}, {'name': 'vishnu', 'data': 'dev'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the solution was to simply seek to the beginning of the document. The json.dump() does overwrite but it only overwrites whats in its way. AKA, seeking/placing the cursor at the top of the document will overwrite the entire document using the new entry.

Comment: No need to seek.